# Frame to div issue, content goes past page height

Tags: html, css

Hello I'm trying to convert an old web site from frames to div's. The code below is the css for the div's. The issue that I'm having is the content div, the results goes past the bottom of the div. I would like it to have the height of %100 cause it need to work with several differnt screeen resolutions. Any help fixing it would be great.

Thanks

```
    <style>
    #wrapper {
        width:100%;
        top:0; bottom:0; right:0; left:0;
        padding:0;
        margin: 0 auto;
         position: absolute;
    }
    body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }
    #header{
    width:100%;
    background-color:#fff;
     } 
    #menu{
    background-color:#fff;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    resize: both;
        }
    #content{
    width:100%;
    float:none;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#fff;
    overflow: auto;
    resize: both;
    position: fixed;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    }
    #footer{
    width:100%;
    position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
    background-color:#fff;

    }
    </style>
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like? That CSS can mean very different things when applied to different HTML pages.

Comment: A JSFiddle would be very helpful http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: The HTML is needed for this, although it's confusing to see both `#menu` and `#content` have set  `height:100%`